# Animate height change

Tags: jquery, css

The following code makes my navbar smaller on scroll and bigger when scrolling back to top: The original height is **15vh** and the smallnav height is **8vh**

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    var nav = $('nav');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 13.35) {
            nav.addClass("smallnav");
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() > 0) {
            nav.removeClass("smallnav");
        }
    });
});
```

Now it just jumps from small to big or the other way around but how can I create an animation for this so that it shrinks or expands?

Comment: Using CSS `transitions` or `animations` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in your `nav` css

```
  -webkit-transition: height 1s; 
  -moz-transition: height 1s; 
  -ms-transition: height 1s; 
  -o-transition: height 1s; 
  transition: height 1s;
```

And it will animate the height change over 1s.

Read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: Good question why someone downvoted you, But if I should guess I think its because you asked for upvotes. I have also been downvoted before because of that.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Lol, then maybe that guy should go through this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat

Comment: @void I agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the following to make a better flow in your change of the height:

```
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var nav = $('nav');

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 13.35) {
      nav.addClass("smallnav");
    } else if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 0) {
      nav.removeClass("smallnav");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
nav {
  height: 15vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.smallnav {
  height: 8vh;
}

body {
  height: 200vh
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>your nav </nav>
```